# Ubuntu 18.04 network adapter lost settings

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, netplan

I have a hosted server at hetzner which has personnel projects running on it. I've come to rely on it and sadly after an apt-get upgrade, I've rebooted and the network adapter doesn't seem to want to assign its static IP address anymore. I'm not sure but it looks like it is moved onto netplan which I'm not familiar with.

I have a /etc/netplan # cat 01-netcfg.yaml file which looks like the correct IP is set. So I'm a little confused as to what I need to do with this. see below.

#### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - x.x.x.x/32
        - x:x:x:x::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: x.x.x.x
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
         lots of dns settings

I've reinstalled netplan.

Sorry for the lack of info but I don't really know where to start.
Any advice for a noob?

Comment: it seems the netplan didnt install successfully and its still using the old method so I wrote a new interface file and its all working again

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses netplan by default out of the box.  How did you come to have an 18.04 system that was "still using the old method"?

Comment: My system was upgraded from a older 16.04 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the netplan didnt install successfully and its still using the old method so I wrote a new interface file and its all working again

It seems upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 didnt go very well

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: `/etc/network/interfaces` lost my `ens160`.
So I added the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto ens160
   iface ens160 inet dhcp
```

I also lost the info in `/etc/netplan/01-network-admin.yaml` and added:

```
ethernets:
  ens160:
     dhcp:  true
```

Once I got that all setup, I was able to restart with...

```
systemctl restart networking
```

...and the interface came back up.